# How to elminitate whitespace from my placeholder in a textarea

Tags: html, textarea, whitespace, placeholder

I'm having some trouble getting white space out of a textarea on my website, I, and a buddy of mine, have looked through the line that I would think the problem would be in and haven't come up with anything after an hour of searching:

```
                        <textarea rows="4" cols="50" type="text" ng-model="delivery.DeliveryInstructions" name= id="txtDeliveryInstructions{{delivery.OrderAddressId}}" placeholder="Clinic will be closed from July 4th to July 5th" class="span12"></textarea>
```

textarea there is a single space at the beginning keeping the ghost text from showing:

> [image: textarea there is a single space at the beginning keeping the ghost text from showing]

textarea after the space is removed showing what it should look like

> [image: textarea after the space is removed showing what it should look like]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to show in jsfiddle just fine with the placeholder showing:

https://jsfiddle.net/qbzy0637/

```
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" type="text" ng-model="delivery.DeliveryInstructions" name= id="txtDeliveryInstructions{{delivery.OrderAddressId}}" placeholder="Clinic will be closed from July 4th to July 5th" class="span12"></textarea>
```

Are you able to send us the rest of the form? or setup a jsfiddle with it so we can see more about this in order to properly understand the form and see all the elements.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/xBLiTzKrIeGx/jo2tafex/

```
                    <body style="text-align:center;">
                      <div class="tooltip">
                        <label>
                          <font color="blue">UPS Ground Used for all Orders:</font>
                        </label>
                        <span class="tooltiptext">Enter possible closing dates that would affect delivery</span>
                      </div>
                      <textarea rows="4" cols="50" type="text" ng-model="delivery.DeliveryInstructions" name=id="txtDeliveryInstructions{{delivery.OrderAddressId}}" placeholder="Clinic will be closed from July 4th to July 5th" class="span12"></textarea>
                      </div>
```

I included the javascript for the tooltip as well so you can see full functionality, also added a paragraph with breaks at the top so the tooltip can be seen on the window provided.

Thanks